# Magento 2 : How to Merge Payment and Shipping Method steps in Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, shipping-methods

Give me useful suggestion, How to merge payment and shipping method steps in checkout.

[image]

Comment: Why you don't use  one step extension?

Answer (score 3):

For starters:

- Create a new checkout step and for the sake of compatibility, upgradability and easy maintenance, do not edit the default Magento code, add your customizations in a separate module.
- Customize the view of the new step, show the required checkout ui components.
- Change the checkout flow.
- Etc.

This is **no small task**, start by reading here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

If you need a good example of modifying the checkout:

https://github.com/danslo/CleanCheckout

and the demo: https://demo.cleancheckout.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can try any One step checkout for that below I have provided some links with paid and free extensions.

**Onestep Checkout**: https://www.onestepcheckout.com/magento-2/

**Amasty**: https://amasty.com/one-step-checkout-for-magento-2.html

**Mageplaza**: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/#section-pricing

**Aheadworks**: https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/one-step-checkout/

**Mageplug**: http://mageplug.net/magento-2-one-step-checkout/

**Coder**: https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout.html

**Bsscommerce**: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout.html

**Iwdagency**: https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html (thay have free also)